# Is there a full range-based standard library implementation available?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, range

After reading "Iterators must go" by Andrei Alexandrescu, I tried to find a replacement for the standard library that uses ranges rather than iterators.

The best I could dig up is `boost::range`, but documentation is pretty weak so I really don't know whether it enables total replacement of iterators when using the standard library.

Is there a reliable and **feature-complete** way to use range-based standard library algorithms?

Comment: Actually, STL is rather proper here since we are effectively concentrating on the Template part of the Library :)

Comment: @MatthieuM.: More, yes. But still not. :) "Forebearer" is the keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) documentation the missing algorithms are (using the same classification as the Standard and the Range documentation):

- Non mutating

  - `all_of`, `any_of`, `none_of` [C++11]
  - `find_if_not` [C++11]
  - `is_permutation` [C++11]
- Mutating

  - `copy_if` [C++11]
  - `move` [C++11]
  - `move_backward` [C++11]
  - `iter_swap`
  - `generate_n`
  - `shuffle` [C++11]
- Partition related

  - `is_partitioned` [C++11]
  - `partition_copy` [C++11]
  - `partition_point` [C++11]
- Sorting related

  - `partial_sort_copy` (*)
  - `is_sorted_until` [C++11]
- Heap related

  - `is_heap_until` [C++11]
- Min/max element

  - `min`, `max`, `minmax` [`minmax` is C++11]
  - `minmax_element` [C++11]

In other words Boost.Range implements pretty much all of C++03 `<algorithm>` (a bit of `<numeric>` too, I didn't check), plus even some of C++11 like `copy_n` and `is_sorted` which were obviously missing. Some of the missing stuff isn't range-related like `min`, `max` and `minmax` (which operate on two elements or one initializer lists of elements) and `iter_swap` (which works on two iterators). There are also documentation bugs as `partial_sort_copy` *does* appear to be here. No dice on `generate_n` which appears to be our sole loser here.

Furthermore, the [use of those algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/introduction.html) is described:

> In its most simple form a Range Algorithm (or range-based algorithm) is simply an iterator-based algorithm where the two iterator arguments have been replaced by one range argument.

with accompanying example:

```
std::vector<int> vec = ...;
boost::sort(vec);
// instead of:
// std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

The one major difference appears to be the return value, where the replacements of Standard algorithms that return one iterator can instead return a range or a single iterator depending on the needs of the user. Details are available [on the same page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/introduction.html) and on the documentation of each individual algorithm. There are also examples.

I think you did a very poor job of reading the documentation.

Comment: you know it could be just that I suck at reading documentation because Im noob and Im  used to tutorials... for example I have no idea what boost::count( rng | boost::adaptors::filtered(pred), out ); does. It doesnt mean that I troll here, it just means that I want to know if learning about boost ranges is worth the time.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Then move on and learn from your mistakes. And don't call documentation 'pretty weak' if you can't read it to begin with. (As to whether Boost.Range is worth it or not that's a different question from what you asked so that I won't address it here.)

Comment: Oh I stand by that comment. I just dont consider documentation to be good.

Answer (score 0):

An update to an old question:

Range-v3 provides not only Ranges, but a range - compatible version of the Standard Library algorithms, piping for composability, both lazy and eager versions and is header-only to boot.  Requires C++11 or newer compiler.

Definitely worth your time if you are interested such things.  https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3

User manual:
https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/